# "gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds" function causes SEGFAULT

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, gtk, gtk3

I'm writing a GTK application where I need to put a string into a GtkTextBuffer and then later extract the same text back out into a separate string. For some reason, I keep receiving a SEGFAULT error during "gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds" function. I think it's a problem with the "e" iterator, but I'm not sure.

I've isolated the offending operations into a smaller example program. There are no differences between the process below and the one in my application.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main ()
{
  const char *string1 = "hello\0", *string2;
  GtkTextBuffer *text = gtk_text_buffer_new (NULL);
  GtkTextIter *s, *e;

  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (text, string1, -1);
  gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds (text, s, e);
  string2 = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (text, s, e, TRUE);
  std::cout << string2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `s` and `e` as pointers, and they are getting default-initialized to `nullptr`, so when `gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds` and `gtk_text_buffer_get_text` get around to using them you get a null pointer dereference and a segfault:

```
GtkTextIter *s, *e;
...
gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds (text, s, e);
...
string2 = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (text, s, e, TRUE);
```

Instead, you could just allocate the `GtkTextIter` objects on the stack and pass their addresses around:

```
GtkTextIter s, e;
...
gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds (text, &s, &e);
...
string2 = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (text, &s, &e, TRUE);
```